# Exception in C# when trying to add a string to strings List

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I get an exception on the List.Add line when trying to run this code:

```
        string searchText = searchByInterestBox.Text;
        List<string> checkedItems = null;

        if (m_BusinessLogic != null)    
        {
            if (searchText != string.Empty)  
            {
                try
                {
                    interestResultBox.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (var itemChecked in InterestsCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        checkedItems.Add(itemChecked.ToString());
                    }
```

While debugging, when reaching the last line of code (checkedItems.Add) it says "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any idea what did I do wrong with the string list?

Thanks a lot.
Itzik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`checkedItems` is `null`, so you are getting an exception. You need to initialize it.

Instead of:

```
List<string> checkedItems = null;
```

Do:

```
IList<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize the list with null:

```
List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have never created an instance of the list, try:

```
List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception means your list has not been created yet (and is still null).

```
 List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
```